# PowerShell retrieve and sort EmailAddresses

Tags: email, powershell, scripting, exchange-server

I'm using the below code for retrieving and simultaneously adding a separator "`,`" for each `smtp`-attribute in the `EmailAddresses`-property.

```
get-mailbox | select-object DisplayName,PrimarySMTPAddress, @{Name='EmailAddresses';Expression={[string]::join(", ", ($_.EmailAddresses))}}
```

But I would also like to sort the values of `EmailAddressess` so that uppercase always comes first by using powershell and with as little effort (short code) as possible.

If you're not familiar with Microsoft Exchange: each value inside `EmailAddresses` first starts with `smtp:` or `SMTP:` followed by the users various email addresses. uppercase SMTP means its the primary SMTP-address used when sending an email for example. Lowercase `smtp` means its just another email address.

I'd like to sort the output so that the `SMTP:*`-value comes first.

Bonus question, in the `Expression`-block; can multiple `[string]::` overloads be used together, if so how?

<del>I was attempting to achieve a sorted output by using `[string]::OrderBy()` and `[string]::OrderByDescending()` but I couldn't figure out how to use them together with `[string]::split()`.</del>

Thanks to user 4c74356b41, I now realize that my string doesn't contain `OrderBy()` or `OrderByDescending()` hence they cannot be used.

[MSDN: OrderBy Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966(v=vs.110).aspx) 
[MSDN: OrderbyDescending Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534855(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: string doesnt contain  `OrderByDescending()` or `OrderBy()`

Comment: That explains it. Thanks.

Comment: you can use `Sort-Object` to sort in powershell. Like so: `$a = @('b','A'); $a | Sort-Object`

Comment: You said: string doesnt contain `OrderbyDescending()` or `OrderBy()`
How do check what string does contain in terms of methods supported.

Comment: `'a' | gm`, so use `Get-Member`, that's one of the 3 basic cmdlets in Powershell. I don't have exchange to test, but you could sort them with `| Sort-Object -Property EmailAddresses` (so using your 'artificial' property)

Comment: Thanks! I'm grateful for clarifying that. I still need to sort the values in the Expression-block.

Comment: That does not work.
`...Expression={[string]::join(", ", ($_.EmailAddresses))| Sort-Object -Property EmailAddresses}}` does not sort the values.

Comment: ah, right, you create a string, i don't think you can do it with this approach.

Comment: Surely it must be some way. :)

Comment: Did you ever get to the bottom of this Niklas?  Ive run into the same issue.  Contact has 5 email addresses with SMTP being last in the collection.  Using EWS to resolve the contact then only gets me EmailAddress1-3 as per API which are unfortunately not the primary address with SMTP

Comment: No, I did not. I believe I did an ugly work-around however... unfortunately I cannot find the script nor remember what I did exactly.

Answer (score -1):

You can just nest a pipeline sort inside of your expression.

```
@{Name='EmailAddresses';Expression={[string]::join(", ", ($_.EmailAddresses | Sort-Object))}}
```

99% sure this will work for you but didn't mock up a full test to be sure so let me know if it fails.

Comment: I never tried with that position of sort-object. Here's however an example that did not work: `...Expression={[string]::join(", ", ($_.EmailAddresses))| Sort-Object -Property EmailAddresses}}` I'll try your suggestion tomorrow.

Comment: yea that woudn't work, by the time you reach the sort stage of that pipeline you have already built your array of objects and then you are asking the pipeline to sort the entire array based the `EmailAddresses` property of each object, so you'll sort the objects themselves, not the emails, putting the sort inside of your expression sorts the emails before adding them to the objects that get added to your array.  does my code work if you run it?

Comment: I've tried it now and it doesn't work unfortunately. I've tried different approaches and none really worked perfectly. What is weird is that the objects are sorted differently but SMTP:* doesn't appear first in all of the cases. 
`...Expression={[string]::join(", ", ($_.EmailAddresses| Sort-Object -Property EmailAddresses))}}`
and: 
 `...Expression={[string]::join(", ", ($_.EmailAddresses| Sort-Object -CaseSensitive))}}` 
and: 
`...Expression={[string]::join(", ", ($_.EmailAddresses| Sort-Object -CaseSensitive -Descending))}}`